# Page_PreInit and events

Tags: asp.net, .net, master-pages, page-lifecycle

I have a question...if I have an asp:Button on my page, and I want that button, when clicked, to switch the masterpage, that would be impossible right?

Impossible because switching the masterpage needs to happen in Page_PreInit...but the button click event doesn't happen until **after** code in Page_PreInit is executed.

So if I had this in my Page_PreInit block:

```
If buttonWasPressed Then
      Me.MasterPageFile = "newMaster.master"
end If
```

It would *never* get executed.

So how can one change the master page file with the click of a button?

Thanks!

Comment: I would think you would need to do a page reload for this to happen. You could store the master page pointer in a session variable or cookie then check for that and set as appropriate.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking exactly what steve wrote, Store a trigger in Session Memory and Reload the page when the button gets clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the click event:

```
Session("Master") = "newMaster.master"
Server.Transfer(Request.Url)
```

In the Page_PreInit:

```
Me.MasterPageFile = Session("Master")
```